# Почему javascript цикл бесконечный?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть простой цикл

```
var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
var links = menu.getElementsByTagName('a');

function clickLink () {
    alert('Click');
    return false;
}  
for (var i=0; i < links.length; i++) {
     if(i=2){
        links[2].onclick = clickLink; 
     }
     //break; 
    }
```

Если дописать break, то скрипт работает, но если его нет, то цикл становиться бесконечным. Почему это происходит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if(i == 2)`, иначе у вас идет присвоение значения переменной и цикл продолжается с 2.

Comment: классика :)

Answer (score 1):

Специально для защиты от таких ошибок придуманы Yoda conditions:

```
if (2 == i)
```

Если вы ошибетесь и напишете `if (2 = i)`, то будет явная ошибка, а не скрытая.